# Which terminology in Android / XML is right: Element or Object?

Tags: android, xml

What's the right terminology to use for `ImageView` in Android / XML.

Some sites call it an "Element"; others call it an "Object".   Which is right?

Comment: Depends if you talk about the XML itself or what is generated from it.

Comment: I'm talking About using These Elements like <Textview/> in XML. Do you call them objects or Elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML, `<ImageView/>` is an *element*; `ImageView` is the name of the element.  `ImageView` is also the name of the *start tag* (`<ImageView>...`) and of the *end tag* (`</ImageView>`).

In Java, `android.widget.ImageView` is *class* from which *objects* may be instantiated.

Comment: Thank you Very Good answer...  Ok imageview..  Is the Element. For example android:textColor is the Attribute and the content #FFFFFF is the value(of Attribute) right?

Comment: Just for let me Now the right Names of the structure

Comment: And What About the equal Sign = and the " "  in surrounding the value.. Do they belong to Attribute or value or Something else?

Comment: Yes, for `android:textColor="#FFFFFF"` in XML, `android:textColor` is the *name* of the attribute whose *value* is `#FFFFFF`.

Comment: The, What About = and ""

Comment: They're simply parts of the syntax of an attribute, as defined by the XML Recommendation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Attribute).